# Read external JSON with Swift

Tags: json, swift, xcode

How would I read JSON from a website, example: `https://example.com/checkifexists.php?name=test`, which would return something like this: `[{"exists":"true"}]` or `[{"exists":"false"}]`. I want to check if that exists and get the value true or false using swift.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I can't actually test it because the sample url doesn't actually return the desired bit of JSON `[{"exists":"true"}] or [{"exists":"false"}]`, but I believe this should do what you're after.

```
    let urlString = "https://example.com/checkifexists.php?name=test"
    let url = URL(string: urlString)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error as Any)
        } else {
            do {
                if let data = data,
                   let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [[String:String]] {
                    if json[0]["exists"] == "true" {
                        print("it exists")
                    } else {
                        print("it does not exist")
                    }
                }
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }.resume()
```

Comment: @MikeKillewald I really appreciate this, but is there a way to simply read the true or false from `[{"exists":"true"}]` or `[{"exists":"false"}]`?

Comment: I have updated my answer to read your particular JSON example. I hope that helps :)

Comment: One more question, sorry :p. On this line `let json = JSON(data: data)` I get the error `Use of unresolved identifier 'JSON'`. Do you know what that is?

Comment: The 'JSON' identifier is a struct provided in the swiftyJSON.swift file I mentioned. So, you will need to download the file from GitHub [link](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/blob/master/Source/SwiftyJSON.swift) then add it to your project tree for this to work. Also, you will need a url that actually returns that requested bit of JSON.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I am a beginner at both iOS development and Swift. I do not write code professionally. I have only returned to programming recently after many many years away from it (again only as a hobbyist).  I am trying to help in the best way I know how with the knowledge I presently have.   That said, please show me your way of doing this, so I can learn. Thanks again.

Comment: @MikeKillewald I downloaded SwiftyJSON and I do not get the error anymore, but it does nothing. I am a beginner as well, so I'm in the same boat as you :p.  Moritz, what is the way to do it instead of SwiftyJSON? Thanks :)

Comment: @FranciscoF. I would guess that the url you are using is not actually returning anything, or is returning something other than what you expect.  I tried passing that exact JSON in via a file instead of a URL and the code I posted worked, but since this is apparently not the correct way to go about this, its all a  moot point.

Comment: @MikeKillewald It is returning exactly [{“exists”:”true”}] or [{“exists”:”false”}]

Comment: In my quest to see this thing through to the end, and learn the correct way of doing this myself, I have updated my answer yet again.  @Moritz, please be gentle, lol ;)